# ASP NET 4 How can I use Data Annotations with DataType Password with a MinLength property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, data-annotations

```
public class ChangePasswordObject {

    [Required] [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    string email;
    [Required]
    string authorization_code;
    [Required] [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    string password;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be as easy as:

```
[Required] 
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
string password;
```

The first parameter to `StringLength` is the *maximum* length.

---

Now for my $0.02:

As noted in the comments, providing minimum and maximum constraints on your password fields tells an attacker a lot about your password requirements, and they could optimize their attack based on this information.

Also, be careful about storing and passing around plaintext passwords -- you should salt+hash them ASAP using a one-way encryption algorithm and a random salt. Verifying passwords should repeat the encryption on the user's input ,using the known salt and comparing the resulting hashes. If you're doing more with a plaintext password than POSTing it, you may want to rethink your security strategy.

Comment: A total aside but a) please don't set a maximum length for a password (at least not one that's under 100chars) and b) don't store passwords at all! You need to hash and salt that or you are being incredibly negligent.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: I definitely agree with your suggestions, and may update my answer to include some extra pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Add a StringLength attribute to the password field.  An example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
[MembershipPasswordAttribute(MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = 4, MinRequiredPasswordLength = 7, MinNonAlphanumericCharactersError = "Alpha", MinPasswordLengthError = "MIN Length")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password",ErrorMessage  ="{0} and {1} should be same")]
public string ComparePassword { get; set; }
```